# How to Remove last inserted div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="file">                                    
<input type="file" name="txtImage" multiple="multiple" class="upload" />  
<input type="text"  name="txtImageDesc" class="desc" /> 
</div>      
<input type="button" value="Add" name="addButton" onclick="javascript: add_more();" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" name="removeButton" onclick="javascript: remove();" />
```

The above is two button which add or remove div on its calls.I have a java script function which is adding a div in html on call which works perfect

```
function  add_more() 
{
var txt = " <p><label>Upload Image</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"txtImage[]\"></p>   <p>
<label>Image Description</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"txtImageDesc[]\"> </p>";
 document.getElementById("file").innerHTML += txt;
}
```

However i am using the same script(with modification) to remove the last inserted div in it but its removing the whole html in the div.Here is the code:

```
function  remove() {
var txt = " <p><label>Upload Image</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"txtImage[]\"></p>    
<p><label>Image Description</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"txtImageDesc[]\"> </p>";
 document.getElementById("file").innerHTML -= txt;
 }
```

The output it generate is.I want the last div inserted to be remove on button click

```
NaN
```

Comment: where is _last div_ ?

Comment: You are not adding any div, are you?

Comment: As you've tagged this question with jquery may I suggest using jquery

Comment: you can use removeChild() function of javascript

Comment: theres no divs and why arent you using jquery?

Comment: you're not using jquery

Comment: I think he want to delete p tag instead of div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#file p').slice(-2).remove();` will remove the last 2 `P` elements from your `#file` element:

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ijacaj/1/edit)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" name="addButton" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" name="removeButton" /> 

<div id="file"></div>
```

jQ:

```
var html = " <p><label>Upload Image</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"txtImage[]\"></p><p><label>Image Description</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"txtImageDesc[]\"></p>";


$('[name=addButton]').click(function(){
    $('#file').append( html );
});
$('[name=removeButton]').click(function(){
  $('#file p').slice(-2).remove();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: slice(-2) works because you are inserting 2 `<p>` element, a better solution is to enclose everithing in a `<div>` and then you can do `$('#file div').last().remove();` this way changing your inner html doesn't break your code

Comment: @Alepac thanks for the great tip, I was lazy to write the same.

Answer (score 3):

As already said in comments, you are adding `p` elements here, not `div`.

If you don’t want to use jQuery, you can do it in “pure JS” as well, like this:

```
function lastParagraphBeGone() { // brilliant function name :-)
  var paragraphs = document.getElementById("file").getElementsByTagName("p");
  var lastParagraph = paragraphs[paragraphs.length-1];
  lastParagraph.parentNode.removeChild(lastParagraph);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript uses the same operator for concatenation and for addition; so adding works.

But the minus operator is only for subtraction. So you try to subtract text from text which aren't numbers, so it's a `NaN`.

You cannot remove by this way: Use some function to search the beginning of this string and extract it so or simply add an `id` attribute to your `<p>` tag, so you can simply hide it when not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. One thing that seems to break this kind of function is when the adding text is on separate lines. So, always put that kind of "txt" addition on a single line in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function  add_more() 
{
var txt = " <p><label>Upload Image</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"txtImage[]\"></p><p><label>Image Description</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"txtImageDesc[]\"> </p>";
 document.getElementById("extra-text").innerHTML = txt;
}

function  remove() {
 document.getElementById("extra-text").innerHTML = '';
 }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Add" name="addButton" onclick="javascript: add_more();" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" name="removeButton" onclick="javascript: remove();" />


<div id="file"><h1>Existing text</h1>

<div id="extra-text"></div>

</div>
```